# label annotation on top of bar using barplot in r

Tags: r, bar-chart

Need to move rotated labels on the top of the bar using barplot. What parameter am I missing here?
code:

```
df<- data.frame(a=strrep(letters[1:20], 10) , b=runif(20, min=1, max=30))
df<- df[order(df$b, decreasing = TRUE),]

row.names(df)<- df$a
par(mar=c(15, 5, 3, 2)+ 0.2)
x<- barplot(df$b, c(2, 4, 1, 6), ylim = c(0, 30), ylab="statistics", col = heat.colors(20), xaxt="n")
label = row.names(df)
text(cex=0.2, x=x, y=-1.25, label, xpd=TRUE, srt=45)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the position of y-axis in `text` with a suitable offset. (I have used + 1 here).

```
x <- barplot(df$b, c(2, 4, 1, 6), ylim = c(0, 30), ylab="statistics", 
            col = heat.colors(20), xaxt="n")
label = row.names(df)

text(cex=0.2, x=x, y=df$b + 1, label, xpd=TRUE, srt=45)
```

Comment: thank you so much! it lights up my day